# Chunky Fluid in Fluid simulation?

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation

Is it possible to have "chunky" fluid in a simulation? I have been playing with adding particles, with a fluid simulation as the emitter, and not getting results I am looking for. The fluid simulation and the particle simulation appear to remain independent. The applications could be anything from pouring spoiled milk, to a mudslide grabbing debris along it's path. I have done searches on google and haven't turned up anything. Any thoughts?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=blender%20molecular%20addon

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos -- Thanks, I'm looking forward to playing with this.